# How yo update chart with script setup?

Tags: vue-chartjs

How can i make the update function rerender the chart? Clicking it does change the ref values but it doesnt change the chart itself. I am confused about using the computed function stated in the doc. Since it is not script setup.

```
<template>
  {{ chartData }}
  <Bar
    id="my-chart-id"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :data="chartData"
  />
  <button
    @click="update()"
    class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
  >
    Button
  </button>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";
  import { ref, computed } from "vue";
  import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    BarElement,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
  } from "chart.js";

  ChartJS.register(
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    BarElement,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale
  );

  const chartData = ref({
    labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
    datasets: [{ data: [40, 20, 12] }],
  });
  const chartOptions = ref(true);

  function update() {
    chartData.value.datasets = [{ data: [0, 2, 2] }];
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do this is to have the chart as a component within a [parent](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#creating-your-first-chart). (This also allows you to have more that one chart in the parent, with each chart being a child component.)

When you add the component to the parent include a :key, for example:

```
<BarChart :key="updateKey" />
```

Changing the value of the key will force a re-render the component.
You can then pass the datasets data as a prop to the child.

So, keep you current code as the child (in this case called BarChart) and create your parent which would would look like:

```
<template>
  <BarChart :key="updateKey" :barChartData="barChartData"/>
  <button @click="update()" >Update </button>
</template>

<script>
import BarChart from 'path/to/component/BarChart'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { BarChart }
  data () { 
    return {
        barChartData = [{ data: [40, 20, 12] }];
        updateKey = 0;
    }
}
methods: {
    update() {
       this.barChartData = [{ data: [0, 2, 2] }];
       this.updateKey ++; // this forces the chart to re-render
    }
}
</script>
```

and then in the BarChart component, simply add the prop and assign to the value to the chart in mounted:

```
props: ["barChartData"],

mounted() {
   this.chartData.datasets = this.barChartData;
},
```

Comment: This is not script setup..